# Regarding customizing sorting the list

Tags: java, list

In an interview an question was asked , that there is a list containg few strings like below shown, have to do character by character comparison

```
cDgHkJ----------->index 0
bAgHtR----------->index 1
aBEfgj----------->index 2
```

Now I have to sort the list , in a way that i should ignore the case that is case insensitive it should be but in the from like this

comparision between index 2 and index 1 as shown below

```
aAEfgj----------->index 1
bBgHtR----------->index 2
```

then comparison between index 1 and index 2

```
cDgHkJ----------->index 0
aAEfgj----------->index 1   ( which we first sorted in first step)
```

-------Final Sorted List---------------

```
aAEfgJ---------> ultimately final sorted list , I want to achieve
cDgHkj----------->index 1  
aBEfgj----------->index 2
```

Please advise how to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're trying to do, but you know of course that the String class has a constant (static final field), `CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` that is a `Comparator<String>`, and can be used by `Collections.sort(...)` or `Arrays.sort(...)`.

Comment: You aren't really clear on how the strings are supposed to be sorted, is it alphabetically? lexicographicly? I don't see how that is the final case insensitive sort.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen alphabetically , string should be sorted

Comment: @TuntunThgjgj How is `cD...` coming before `aB...` then ?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels so Collecton.sort will work , Shall I go for comaprator

Comment: @TuntunThgjgj: I don't know what you should do. Your post is *very* confusing to say the least. So you are sorting the characters held *in the String itself*?

Answer (score -1):

You can do this easily by defining your own comparator which compares both strings *after* they have been forced to either lower or upper case:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();

// fill with strings

Collections.sort(strings, 
                 new Comparator<String>() { 
                     @Override
                     public int compare(String s1, String s2) { 
                         return s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase()); 
                     }
                 }
);
```

Comment: Use `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` instead: `Collections.sort(strings, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)`

Comment: Exactly as per my comment 35 minutes ago. This answer is introducing unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström so the above program shown by you will be modified, could you please do the update .Thanks in advance

Comment: Did this really deserve a downvote though? I am showing an alternative to what you suggested in the comments.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Sorry, i should have referenced your comment.